# How to use Apache Commons Net to fetch an email via IMAP?

Tags: java, imap, apache-commons-net

I've successfully connected and logged in to the IMAP server and can use the IMAP fetch command to retrieve a list of emails. However, when I try to retrieve a single email with full headers I end up having a problem.

This is the stack trace I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.net.MalformedServerReplyException: Received unexpected IMAP protocol response from server: 'Return-Path: <[removed]>'.
at org.apache.commons.net.imap.IMAPReply.getReplyCode(IMAPReply.java:128)
at org.apache.commons.net.imap.IMAPReply.getReplyCode(IMAPReply.java:93)
at org.apache.commons.net.imap.IMAP.__getReply(IMAP.java:120)
at org.apache.commons.net.imap.IMAP.__getReply(IMAP.java:90)
at org.apache.commons.net.imap.IMAP.sendCommandWithID(IMAP.java:225)
at org.apache.commons.net.imap.IMAP.sendCommand(IMAP.java:238)
at org.apache.commons.net.imap.IMAP.sendCommand(IMAP.java:263)
at org.apache.commons.net.imap.IMAP.doCommand(IMAP.java:276)
at org.apache.commons.net.imap.IMAPClient.fetch(IMAPClient.java:339)
```

My code that generates the above stack trace is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    IMAPClient client = new IMAPClient();
    client.connect(SERVER);
    client.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    client.select("INBOX");
    client.fetch("1", "body[header]");
}
```

I'm using commons-net-3.1

When I connect to the IMAP server via telnet and issue the same command I end up with a result like this (I've elided some of the data with underscores):

```
08 fetch 1 body[header]
* 1 FETCH (BODY[HEADER] {608}
Return-Path: <____@____.com>
X-Original-To: ____@____.com
Delivered-To: ____@____.com
Received: from ____.____.com (unknown [____])
    by ____.____.____ (Postfix) with ESMTP id 1926514D20
    for <____@____.com>; Mon,  1 Feb 2010 16:52:36 +1100 (EST)
Date: Mon, 1 Feb 2010 16:52:35 +1100 (EST)
From: ____@____.com
To: ____@____.com
Message-ID: <__________________________@_____>
Subject: ____
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_13575_1460176524.1265003555921"

)
* 79690 EXISTS
* 13 RECENT
08 OK Fetch completed.
```

Am I using the correct method (fetch) to view the email?
Any clues on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using FETCH 1 full

Comment: "FETCH 1 full" works. However it gives me less data than "FETCH 1 BODY[HEADER]" and "FETCH 1 BODY[TEXT]".

Answer (score 1):

That is the correct usage of fetch (according to mailing list). This is a bug in commons-net.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NET-467